# How to launch a new docker container from inside a docker container on openshift

Tags: docker, openshift-origin

**Usecase:**

I want to write a server application that launches a docker container per customer with only the specific customer data inside (for data protection). The service should run on openshift or openshift origin.

**Where I have searched:**

[openshift origin latest documentation](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/welcome/index.html)

[openshift origin m4 documentation](https://docs.openshift.org/origin-m4/index.html)

**What I already know:**

I can launch a docker container from inside a docker container if the first container is a privileged container or the docker socket and binary from the host is linked into it.

*[Edit 31.10.15] Like: `docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ...`*

**What I don't know:**

Is it possible to launch a privileged docker container on openshift or use the openshift api from inside the docker container to launch an other docker container (with specific runtime configuration)? BTW: the "mother" container should be scalable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible - OpenShift does the same thing to run the build container that performs Docker and source builds.  On the container security context (in your pod definition) set priviliged to true and define your volume mount of /var/run/docker.sock.

Note that you'll need to have the authority to launch priviliged containers (regular users aren't allowed to set priv or host mount), which can be done by adding your project to the "priviliged" security context constraint (https://docs.openshift.org/latest/admin_guide/manage_scc.html).  In 1.0.7 there is a policy command that makes it easier `oc policy add-scc-to-service-account`

Comment: I've created a new service account and I'm able to add it in oc edit scc privileged, but which policy do I have to give to my service account after the creation?

Comment: or is it fine to perform this for the deployer sa of the project?

Answer (score 3):

After reading "[`~jpetazzo/`Using Docker-in-Docker for your CI or testing environment? Think twice.](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/)", I would consider usings sibbling containers instead of nested containers.
The following extract talsk about CI but could be applied to an openshift launching containers per client (instead of a CI launching containers)

> Do you really want Docker-in-Docker? Or do you just want to be able to run Docker (specifically: build, run, sometimes push containers and images) from your CI system, while this CI system itself is in a container?
>
> The simplest way is to just expose the Docker socket to your CI container, by bind-mounting it with the `-v` flag.
>
> Simply put, when you start your CI container (Jenkins or other), instead of hacking something together with Docker-in-Docker, start it with:

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ...
```

> Now this container will have access to the Docker socket, and will therefore be able to start containers. Except that instead of starting "child" containers, it will start "sibling" containers.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have read that already but haven't linked it because i'm new to stackoverflow and could only add two links ;-) The main problem i have is that i don't know if it's possible to do this trick on openshift.

Comment: @ChristianWitt I agree, I simply though that persistent data in a container itself in a container was a bit too risky.

Comment: Of course the persistent data should not stay in the container, but the idea is to setup a new container runtime per user (like different enviroment variables and so on) so that a running container have only access to the needed data. For example container A launches container B with something like `docker run -v /data/user1:/data ...` and container C with something like `docker run -v /data/user2:/data ...`

Comment: The only issue with sibling containers on CI is that they require explicit cleanup. If build job is in container C1 was failed "job manager" will kill that container. But not the containers spawned from C1 during the build